# How to prevent the OpenSSH warning about host key offence?

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, openssh

I have a hosted git repository in my own server and my git repo URL looks like this:

```
ssh://username@example.com/var/git-repo-path
```

When I am pushing to the server using Git GUI, I get the following warning.

[image]

I can still type 'yes' and skip this screen. But I want to know how to fix this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would fix this by deleting the line containing the outdated host key in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. (It looks like the full path on your system is `G:\Users\Lenin\.ssh\known_hosts`.)

Host key checking is a good thing.

If for some reason you really want to disable the checking, you could add this to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host example.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Comment: It was a charm. Deleted known_hosts under G:\Users\Lenin\.ssh and did a push once and Git GUI added the latest keys under known hosts. Further push didnt show this warning...